# multiple id parameter in routing

Tags: node.js, express

I have this routing:

```
GET /something/:id/details/:id
```

and when I log

```
console.log(req.params);
```

it only returns last id parameter. How can I catch both ids? Is this possible?

Comment: try changing the second one, :idsomething

Comment: yes I can but I want to experiment if that is possible

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Answer (score 1):

just rename the second param name

```
GET /something/:id/details/:otherId
```

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to have two parameters property name to be same.

> [`req.params`](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params) property is an object containing properties mapped to the named route “parameters”.

In case, if two property names are same. The last one override the previous one. This is because properties in an object are processed in order.

To catch both parameters, rename one of them

```
GET /something/:id/details/:id1
```

Now, your `req.params` will give you both of your property.